# Stackoverflow-like text editing

Tags: discussion, editor, implementation

We use a markup style system in a CMS. It works in a similar way to the system used for asking questions on stackoverflow (though it uses a different syntax).

I am curious if the text editing system used by stackoverflow (that I am typing into now) is a commercially available plug-in or if it was developed by the team.

What I really want to figure out how to do is add buttons for **bold** etc that manipulate the text inside the `textarea`, but I am having trouble tracking down suitable information. The URL button seems the most complicated, as it will renumber all the references throughout your text if needed...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can download the editor [here.](http://github.com/derobins/wmd) And read up on the process [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/wmd-editor-reverse-engineered/).

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. I can spend the rest of the day looking though the code... :-)

Comment: On the page it says `This repository is no longer maintained. Please use PageDown instead.` here is the link https://github.com/ujifgc/pagedown

Answer (score 3):

You can look at all tools used to build SO right [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with). As you can see, the editor WMD for Markdown is open source.